# Utilizing custom environment paths from other programs with batch file proccesing

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd, parameters, environment-variables

I have visited StackOverflow thousands of times and it's always incredibly useful.  This will be my first question on this site, after spending the entire day attempting to solve a problem.

Long story short, I use a program who's configuration settings allow for custom user programs to be executed with a button click on the main GUI.  Alongside this is an input for a cmd line option.  You can see the config in this image.

[Configuration Settings Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5MSY.png)

So I have created a script to execute and have been trying with no success for the entire day.  I don't imagine I have to explain what it's like to keep changing small details and even starting over again a dozen times.  Basically, when you highlight an order in the program, I want to move any (*.stl) files from the orders folder.   The .bat file converted to exe i tried dozens and dozens of similar scripts like the code below.  I have a .bat and a .exe that work fine when I am moving a file from my own directories.  But now with this very new to me, environment variable.  No matter how I format it, it doesn't work.  In the beginning it was always exit code 255.  But now I get exit codes 0, 1, but no file copy.  I have made progress and but decided I need to ask for help.

Thank you in advance.

edit: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgYRK.png)

```
for /r %ORDER_FOLDER% %f in (*.stl*) do @copy %f C:\Users\Lap2\Desktop\test_dir
```

Comment: Is it possible that the ORDER_FOLDER variable contains a SPACE or other special character? Use the command `SET ORDER_` to see the value. It is best practice to always quote a path. `for /r "%ORDER_FOLDER%" %f in (*.stl*) do @copy %f "C:\Users\Lap2\Desktop\test_dir"`

Comment: You should also quote `copy "%f" ...`

Comment: I made the modifications you suggested and received exit code 1 and no copies.  Set in cmd doesnt reveal the directory unless I start in that directory and the console doesnt open from this programs use of it so I cannot set the environment.  I assumed, it was done already by the program, so i tried entering a custom parameter.   'start "" "%ORDER_FOLDER%"' but this did not work.

Comment: @Stephan, yes, I forgot to quote %f. Actually, I think it would be better to use `"%~f"`

Comment: @lit: the given `for` loop will never quote its results, but `~` definitively doesn't hurt either.

Comment: @Stephan, it is a best practice to ingrain to always quote paths.